# google prettify: ada syntax

Tags: ada, google-code-prettify

I am currently trying to highlight Ada code on my website using [google prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted) and a file I have found [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=312).
However, I am not able to use the later file with prettify, and the automatic language detection messes up attributes with ' characters (such as Array'first or integer'image), and highlights them as string delimiters.

for instance, I have the following sample code, and I would like to have it formatted correctly in my page:

```
procedure mergesort (V: in out TV_integer; iterations: in out integer) is
-- {} => {V is sorted}
    m : integer := (V'first + V'last) / 2;
begin -- mergesort
    if V'length > 1 then
        mergesort(V(V'first..m), iterations);
        mergesort(V(m+1..V'last), iterations);
        merge(V(V'first..m),V(m+1..V'last),V,iterations);
    end if;
end mergesort;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried using a *pre class="prettyprint lang-ada"* tag so that it would use the lang-ada custom script, but without success.

Comment: If automatic language detection doesn't work, you should be able to specify the language with a CGI parameter, probably "lang=ada". I don't know whether Ada is supported.

Comment: I tried using <pre class="prettyprint lang-ada"> so that it would use the lang-ada custom script, but without success.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm the author of the Ada lexer for google code prettify. To use it, add this to your page:

```xml
<head>
    <!-- ... -->

    <link href="css/prettify.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lang-ada.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

Do *not* use the auto-loader, it won't use custom lexers (change the paths to where you put the files of google code prettify). After you have done that, you can highlight code on your website like this:

```xml
<pre class="prettyprint lang-ada"><code>
-- Ada code
</code></pre>
```

or if you're using markdown or something else that prevents you from adding classes to your tags:

```xml
<?prettify lang=ada?>
<pre><code>
-- here goes your Ada code
</code></pre>
```

By the way, the Ada lexer will mark Ada attributes with the class `atn` (which is colored violet by default). If you want them to have the same color as other code, just edit `prettify.css`.

Comment: Yes. The only thing Ada 2012 added on the lexer side is the `some` keyword, so that wasn't much of a problem ;).

Comment: Re "Do not use the auto-loader, it won't use custom lexers", the auto-loader will use custom lexers if you specify `&lang=...`.  I just need to incorporate the ada patch.

Answer (score 2):

Ada is not supported. A lexer has been submitted by fordprefect86, but has not (yet) been included.
See [Issue 312](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=312) for more information